# Firefox-Addon: Add search engine with varying URL and suggestions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

my Firefox addon shall add a search engine, that

- provides suggestions
- gets its search template URL specified on runtime (i.e.: template URL depends on the preferences of the user)

And I don't see a way to do both at the same time.

I see two options to add a search engine:

- [`addEngineWithDetails`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserSearchService#addEngineWithDetails%28%29)
- [`addEngine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserSearchService#addEngine%28%29)

`addEngineWithDetails()` allows me to add a search engine with the template URL. But it does (apparently?) not allow to provide a suggestions URL.

`addEngine()` allows me to add a search engine that is specified in an XML file. But if have that file saved locally in my addon directory (e.g. `chrome://example-engine/content/search.xml`), how can I change the template URL on runtime? And using an online XML is an unsafe options since the internet connection could be broken or bad during the addon install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fo all, you're right, `addEngineWithDetails` does not support suggestions.

The way to go would be to use [`addEngine`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/public/nsIBrowserSearchService.idl#209) (and `removeEngine`).

As for the "dynamic" part of your question: While I didn't test it, the implementation seems to happily [accept `data:` URIs](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/search/nsSearchService.js#1092). So you could:

- Construct a data URI using whatever methods you like (even constructing a full XML DOM and serializing it).
- Call `addEngine` with the data URI.
- When the user changes a pref, remove the old engine, and construct a new one.